# How to refresh metadata in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, windows, music, metadata

I've updated much of my songs' metadata using `MusicBrainz Picard` and it's successfully updated in the `.mp3` files. However, a song's updated metadata is not reflected in iTunes until I play it. Is there a way to refresh this data for all the songs at once.

Also, just for testing, I dropped a music folder into iTunes. Instead of updating the song's metadata, it added the songs again and now I have duplicates.

PS: I am on Windows 8.1

Comment: I only know a way to achieve this via AppleScript, thanks to DougScripts. BUT, i have seen some people doing some VBA coding, that was pretty similar to AppleScript code.

Comment: found them, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Found a VBA Script here :
http://samsoft.org.uk/itunes/UpdateTagInfo.vbs

You can find many other scripts there too:
http://samsoft.org.uk/itunes/scripts.asp